# Http2 nginx and chrome

Tags: nginx, http2

So I enabled http2 on nginx (nginx/1.10.1) with following config

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;

   ....
}
```

When I preform request with curl `curl  -I https://example.com` I get response:

```
HTTP/2.0 200
date:Tue, 13 Sep 2016 09:41:11 GMT
content-type:text/html
....
```

When I do same request in chrome response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 13 Sep 2016 09:43:43 GMT 
Content-Type: text/html
```

Why is chrome not switching to http2? I am missing something here?

Comment: Possibly due to this. https://www.nginx.com/blog/supporting-http2-google-chrome-users/

Comment: Ok let me try upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS